What is the correct order of using Vagrantfile commnads along with provision.sh file?
I am trying to create an Ubuntu 24.04 box with Vagrant. I have configured a few configuration options in the vagrantfile and quite a few in the provision.sh file. Both files contents are posted below. However, it looks like my Provision.sh file is not being executed at all. I need help resolve the issue so I can properly configure my box.
Vagrantfile:
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64"

  config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
    v.gui = true
  end
  
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
    v.name = "my_vm"
    v.gui = true
    v.check_guest_additions = false
  end

  # Provisioning Script
  config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
    v.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"
  end

provision.sh:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Change the Default Keyboard Layout
sudo sed -i 's/"fr"/"us"/g' /etc/default/keyboard

# Install OS updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y

# Disable Unix Firewall
sudo ufw disable

# Install Desktop Tools
sudo apt install -y open-vm-tools-desktop build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) curl wget git vim nano bash-completion

sudo poweroff


You shouldn't need to lock the provisioner to a specific provider, use the following generalized shell provisioner instead:
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64"

  config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
    v.gui = true
  end
  
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
    v.name = "my_vm"
    v.gui = true
    v.check_guest_additions = false
  end

  # Provisioning Script
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "./provision.sh"
end

If you still hit some issues, try running vagrant up --debug instead so we can get more detailed logs of what might be going wrong.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Don't be a lazy reviewer, I've been on S/O for eight years and I know how to write an answer. If your only criteria is "I don't see a link, bad answer", you should rethink your process.

Thanks for the answer, however, I am unable to understand the need to define all the rest of the providers when I am using only ONE provider. I can run Vagrant up --debug but the output will be too big for this post, I can save the output to Gist and share a link here if you like.

@BlueGrass you defined multiple providers in your question, all I did was copy them. If you only need one provider, only specify that provider.

Not sure why I had two providers in there, but removed the first one and reran the installation once again and it worked. Thanks for your help @ajmeese7
